# Salesforce for Outlook Event sync

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Anyone know if its possible to force SF for Outlook to sync immediately after a user has selected the "Sync with Salesforce" category for an Event, rather than wait the standard 10 mins for the sync to kick in?

Alternatively, is there a way to add a button to Outlook that replicates the effect of the Sync Now menu option in the SF for Outlook task bar (so its more visible to users)?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Salesforce for Outlook icon from your system tray and select Sync -> Sync Now

Comment: I wasn't clear - I'm looking to replicate that within outlook rather than in the system tray e.g. like the create case button

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have anything like that built in. You can post an idea in ideaexchange